# Django unable to render form in class based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a **function based view** which output a **form**, but when I'm trying to do it in **class based view** **can't see any form** on page and there is no error too

function based view

```
def edit_post(request,id):

    posts=Post.objects.get(id=id)
    forms = PostForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=posts)
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            uncommit = form.save(commit=False)

            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
        else:
          print form.errors
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "edit_post.html", {'forms': forms,'posts':posts})
```

Class based view

```
class CourseEntryCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'edit_post.html'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.course = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['id'])
        return super(CourseEntryCreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        # self.object.course = self.course
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Im still learning django, if any **changes to be done in class based view** please let me know

Any help is appreciated ..Thanks in advace

Comment: please show the content of your `edit_post.html` file. In the class based view, your form will be named `form`, not `forms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function based view is confused, because it is using two variables `form` and `forms`. You should change it to only use `form`. Then update your template to use `{{ form }}` instead of `{{ forms }}`.

Once you have fixed the template, the form should display in the template. If you are editing an existing objects, you should use `UpdateView` instead of `CreateView`. You shouldn't have to override `dispatch` or `form_value`, there are normally better approaches.